# How can I solve createState function for ... returned an old or invalid state instance?

Tags: validation, flutter, dart, widget, assertion

I constantly receive this error whenever i scroll between two or more forms, the error is solved when i change this line: _SiteFormState createState() => state; to _SiteFormState createState() => new _SiteFormState;
but i want to preserve the states for form validation, how can i achieve this?

This is my code:

```
  import 'dart:ui';
  import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
  import 'package:xperience/models/site.dart';
  import 'package:xperience/models/category.dart';
  import 'package:string_validator/string_validator.dart';

  typedef OnDelete();

  class SiteForm extends StatefulWidget {
  final ManageSiteModel site;
   _SiteFormState state = new _SiteFormState();
  final OnDelete onDelete;

   SiteForm({Key key, this.site, this.onDelete}) : super(key: key);
   @override
  _SiteFormState createState() => state;


  bool isValid() => state.validate();
  }

  class _SiteFormState extends State<SiteForm> {
   @override
  void dispose() {
   super.dispose();
  }


  @override
  void initState() {
  super.initState();
  }
  final form = new GlobalKey<FormState>();
  bool status=false;
  List<bool>statuses=new List<bool>();
  static List<String> _dropdownItems = ["Adventures and 
    Games","Beaches","Mountains","Hikes","Waterfalls and Lakes","Road Trips","Camps"];
  String _dropdownValue= _dropdownItems[0];

    List<Category>categories=[new Category(false,null),new Category(false,null),new 
     Category(false,null),new Category(false,null)];

     String _errorText='';
    TextEditingController _text = new TextEditingController();
    bool _validate = false;

    var regex=new RegExp("([A-Za-z]+[0-9]|[0-9]+[A-Za-z])[A-Za-z0-9]*");
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
     statuses.add(false);
     }
   widget.site.categoryName=_dropdownValue;


      return Container(
       padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
       child: Material(
       elevation: 1,
       clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
       borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
       child: Form(

       key: form,
       child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: <Widget>[
          AppBar(
            leading: Icon(Icons.location_on),
            elevation: 0,
            title: Text('Xsite'),
            backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey,
            centerTitle: true,
            actions: <Widget>[
              IconButton(
                icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
                onPressed: widget.onDelete,
              )
            ],
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, right: 16, top: 16),
            child: TextFormField(
                onChanged: (String value) {
                  setState(() {
                     if(value.length==0){
                      categories[0].filled=false;
                      categories[0].error="This field is required";
                      widget.site.name = "";
                      }
                    else{
                      categories[0].filled=true;
                      categories[0].error=null;
                      widget.site.name = value;
                    }
                  });
                },
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                errorText: categories[0].error,
                labelText: 'Site Name*',
                hintText: "Enter the name of a specific place",
               // errorText: statuses[0] ? 'Value Can\'t Be Empty' : null,
                icon: Icon(Icons.add_location),
                isDense: true,
              ),

            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, right: 16, bottom: 9),
            child: TextFormField(
              onChanged: (String value) {

                setState(() {

                  if(isAlpha(value)) {

                    categories[1].filled=true;
                    categories[1].error=null;
                    widget.site.country = value;

                  }
                  else if(value.length==0){
                    categories[1].filled=false;
                    categories[1].error="This field is required";
                    widget.site.country = "";
                  }
                  else{
                    categories[1].filled=false;
                    categories[1].error="Only contain alphabets";
                    widget.site.country = "";
                  }

                });


              },
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                labelText: 'Country*',
                hintText: 'Enter the country of the site',
                icon: Icon(Icons.my_location),
                isDense: true,
                errorText: categories[1].error,
              ),

            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, right: 16, bottom: 9),
            child: TextFormField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                labelText: 'City*',
                hintText: 'Enter the City of the site',
                icon: Icon(Icons.location_city),
                isDense: true,
                errorText: categories[2].error,
                //errorText: statuses[1] ? 'Value Can\'t Be Empty' : null,
              ),
              onChanged: (String value) {
                setState(() {
                  if(isAlpha(value)) {

                    categories[2].filled=true;
                    categories[2].error=null;
                    widget.site.city = value;

                  }
                  else if(value.length==0){
                    categories[2].filled=false;
                    categories[2].error="This field is required";
                    widget.site.city = "";
                  }
                  else{
                    categories[2].filled=false;
                    categories[2].error="Only contain alphabets";
                    widget.site.city = "";
                  }


                });

              },
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, right: 16, bottom: 16),
            child: TextFormField(
              validator: (val) =>
              inrange(widget.site.mapAddress) ? null : 'Address is invalid',
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                labelText: 'Google maps address',
                hintText: 'E.g: 24.658154, 26.225756',
                icon: Icon(Icons.map),
                isDense: true,
                errorText: categories[3].error,
              ),
              onChanged: (String value){
                setState(() {
                if(!inrange(value)) {
                  categories[3].filled = false;
                  categories[3].error = 'Wrong format of map address';
                  widget.site.mapAddress = "";
                }
                else{
                  categories[3].filled=true;
                  categories[3].error=null;
                  widget.site.mapAddress = value;


                }
                  });


              },
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 15.0, right: 0, bottom: 11),
              child:Row(children: <Widget>[
                Icon(Icons.category,color: Colors.grey,),
                Text('  Category of Site',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue,fontSize: 15.0),)
              ]
              )
          ),

        ],
      ),
    ),
   ),
     );
     }

///form validator
bool validate() {

bool val=true;
  if(widget.site.city=="" || !isAlpha(widget.site.city)){
    setState(() {
      categories[2].error="This field is required";
      val=false;
    });
  }
   if(widget.site.country=="" || !isAlpha(widget.site.country)){
    setState(() {
      categories[1].error="This field is required";
      val=false;
    });
  }
   if(widget.site.name=="" || !isAlpha(widget.site.name)){
    setState(() {
      categories[0].error="This field is required";
      val=false;
    });
  }
  for(int i=0;i<categories.length;i++){
    if(!categories[i].filled){
      val=false;
    }
  }

  if(!val){
    return false;
  }
  print(val);
  print("formaaaaaaaatology");
  return true;
  }
  bool inrange(String maps){
int count=0;
if(maps.length==0){
  return true;
  }

for (int i=0;i<maps.length;i++){
  if(maps[i]==','){
    count++;
  }
}
if(count==0 || count>1){
  return false;
}

double min=double.parse(maps.substring(0,maps.indexOf(',')));
double max=double.parse(maps.substring(maps.indexOf(',')+1,maps.length));

 if(!(min>=-90 && min<=90)){
  return false;
}

else if(!(max>=-180 && max<=80)){
  return false;
}
else {
  return true;
};
    }
    validateCountry(val){
    if(val.length>0 ) {
     print("koukeyeee");
     setState(() {
      this.widget.site.country="kousaay";
      });
      return null;
     }
   return 'This field is required';
   }
  }
```

This is the code that calls the form validation in the other page:

```
  bool onSave() {
  if (sites.length > 0) {
   var allValid = true;

  sites.forEach((form) => allValid=form.validate() );
  if (allValid) {
    var data = sites.map((it) => it.site).toList();
    Navigator.push(context,MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ConnectorBiography()),);
    return true;
  }
  else{
    print("noot valid");
    return false;
  }
  else{
     Text("failed");
     }
    }
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I fixed my problem by editing my class to :

```
class SiteForm extends StatefulWidget {
final ManageSiteModel site;
final OnDelete onDelete;

//adding new to this will remove the forms.
var state= _SiteFormState();

SiteForm({Key key, this.site, this.onDelete}) : super(key: key);

@override
_SiteFormState createState(){
return this.state=new _SiteFormState();
}

bool isValid() => this.state.validate();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this! this made my day!

Comment: glad! @KrishnaShetty

Comment: Man, you saved me. Thanks a lot. I was having a weird exception

Comment: glad to hear! @Jorge

Comment: This solution works 100%, but it would be helpful if somebody actually explained why this works.